# Node.js using amazon transcoder to format video / audio files

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

My goal is to make sure that all videos that are being uploaded to my application is the right format and that they are formatted to fit minimum size.

I did this before using `ffmpeg` however i have recently moved my application to an amazon server.

This gives me the option to use [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/)

However by the looks of it from the interface i am unable to set up automatic jobs that look for video or audio files and converts them.

For this i have been looking at their SDK / api references but i am not quite sure how to use that in my application.

My question is has anyone successfully started transcoding jobs in `node.js` and know how to convert videos from one format to another and / or down set the bitrate?  I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction with some examples of how this might work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> However by the looks of it from the interface i am unable to set up
>   automatic jobs that look for video or audio files and converts them.

The Node.js SDK doesn't support it but you can do the followings: if you store the videos in S3 (if not move them to S3 because elastic transcoder uses S3) you can run a Lambda function on S3 putObject triggered by AWS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

> My question is has anyone successfully started transcoding jobs in
>   node.js and know how to convert videos from one format to another and
>   / or down set the bitrate? I would really appreciate it if someone
>   could point me in the right direction with some examples of how this
>   might work.

We used AWS for video transcoding with node without any problem. It was time consuming to find out every parameter, but I hope these few line could help you:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: config.AWS.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: config.AWS.secretAccessKey,
  region: config.AWS.region
});

var transcoder = new aws.ElasticTranscoder();

let transcodeVideo = function (key, callback) {
    // presets: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/system-presets.html
    let params = {
      PipelineId: config.AWS.transcode.video.pipelineId, // specifies output/input buckets in S3 
      Input: {
        Key: key,
      },
      OutputKeyPrefix: config.AWS.transcode.video.outputKeyPrefix, 
      Outputs: config.AWS.transcode.video.presets.map(p => {
        return {Key: `${key}${p.suffix}`, PresetId: p.presetId};
      })
    };

    params.Outputs[0].ThumbnailPattern = `${key}-{count}`;
    transcoder.createJob(params, function (err, data) {
      if (!!err) {
        logger.err(err);
        return;
      }
      let jobId = data.Job.Id;
      logger.info('AWS transcoder job created (' + jobId + ')');
      transcoder.waitFor('jobComplete', {Id: jobId}, callback);
    });
  };
```

An example configuration file:

```
let config = {
  accessKeyId: '',
  secretAccessKey: '',
  region: '',
  videoBucket: 'blabla-media',
  transcode: {
    video: {
      pipelineId: '1450364128039-xcv57g',
      outputKeyPrefix: 'transcoded/', // put the video into the transcoded folder
      presets: [ // Comes from AWS console
        {presetId: '1351620000001-000040', suffix: '_360'},
        {presetId: '1351620000001-000020', suffix: '_480'}
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Can you give some insight into what: config.AWS.transcode.video.outputKeyPrefix AND config.AWS.transcode.video is set to?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I updated my answer. I hop it helps. :)

Comment: Life saver this worked 100% I like what you did with the preset array.

Comment: where can I get the "secretAccessKey" in AWS, I went to account menu in the upper-right (has my name on it) then sub-menu: Security Credentials, inside that "Access keys (access key ID and secret access key)" option available but there I get only

Created   |   Access Key ID    |    Last Used     |    Last Used Region     |     Last Used Service |    Status     | Actions

** There is no Secret Access Key available, only Access Key Id available. Can you please tell me where I can find it.?

Comment: You can find more info here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-find-update-access-keys-password-mfa-aws-management-console/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate master playlist you can do it like this.
".ts" files can not playable via hls players. Generate ".m3u8" file

```
async function transcodeVideo(mp4Location, outputLocation) {
let params = {
    PipelineId: elasticTranscoderPipelineId,
    Input: {
        Key: mp4Location,
        AspectRatio: 'auto',
        FrameRate: 'auto',
        Resolution: 'auto',
        Container: 'auto',
        Interlaced: 'auto'
    },
    OutputKeyPrefix: outputLocation + "/",
    Outputs: [
        {
            Key: "hls2000",
            PresetId: "1351620000001-200010",
            SegmentDuration: "10"
        },
        {
            Key: "hls1500",
            PresetId: "1351620000001-200020",
            SegmentDuration: "10"
        }
        ],
    Playlists: [
        {
            Format: 'HLSv3',
            Name: 'hls',
            OutputKeys: [
                "hls2000",
                "hls1500"
            ]
        },
    ],
};

let jobData = await createJob(params);
return jobData.Job.Id;

}

async function createJob(params) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transcoder.createJob(params, function (err, data) {
        if(err) return reject("err: " + err);
        if(data) {
            return resolve(data);
        }
    });
});
```

}